# how to disable a radion button in angular inside my radio group based on condition

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

my radio group has 3 radio button but I only want to disable certain buttons and not all button , how do to that in angular , like disable only selected buttons and not all buttons inside mat-radio-group.

for example I want only to disable the mat-radio-button Sale from the mat radio group , the button should not be clickable.

does anyone has an idea how to make this possible in angular? Thanks.

```
 <mat-radio-group [disabled]="isEditing && dealData !== null" (change)="onChangeDispositionType($event)" [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType">
            <div class="deal-form-header-labels">What type of idle disposition deal would you like to submit? (*)</div>
              <div class="flex" style="justify-content: space-between;">
                <div class="deal-form-btn-group w-30per" [ngClass]="{'v-bg-color':dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Buyout'}">
                  <div class="deal-form-btn-group-radio">
                    <mat-radio-button
                      *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Buyout' else Buyout"    
                      color="accent"  
                      [value]="'Buyout'">
                      <span class="alter-text-color">Buyout</span>
                    </mat-radio-button>
                    <ng-template #Buyout>
                      <mat-radio-button
                        [value]="'Buyout'">
                        Buyout
                      </mat-radio-button>
                    </ng-template>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div  class="deal-form-btn-group w-30per" [ngClass]="{'v-bg-color':dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Sale'}">
                  <div class="deal-form-btn-group-radio">
                    <mat-radio-button
                    disabled
                    *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Sale' else Sale"    
                      color="accent"
                      [value]="'Sale'">
                     <span class="alter-text-color">Sale</span>
                    </mat-radio-button>
                    <ng-template #Sale>
                      <mat-radio-button
                        [value]="'Sale'">
                        Sale
                      </mat-radio-button>
                    </ng-template>
                  </div>
                  
                </div> 
                <div class="deal-form-btn-group w-30per" [ngClass]="{'v-bg-color':dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Sublease'}">
                  <div class="deal-form-btn-group-radio">
                    <mat-radio-button
                    *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Sublease' else Sublease"    
                      color="accent"
                      [value]="'Sublease'">
                     <span class="alter-text-color">Sublease</span>
                    </mat-radio-button>
                    <ng-template #Sublease>
                      <mat-radio-button
                        [value]="'Sublease'">
                        Sublease
                      </mat-radio-button>
                    </ng-template>
                  </div>
                  
                </div> 
              </div>
            </mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: What has this to do with TS?

Comment: @Aaradhya Patel start with minimal reproducible example

Comment: you can use `[disabled]="condition"` for mat-radio-button.

Comment: ikt's only use the property [disabled](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api#MatRadioButton), e.g. `<mat-radio-button [disabled]="myvariable">` and you give value true or false to a variable

Comment: thankss , appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<mat-radio-button
   [disabled]="dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Sale'"   
   color="accent"
   [value]="'Sale'"
>
   <span class="alter-text-color">Sale</span>
</mat-radio-button>
```